# Google search says No information is available for my GitHub page

Tags: google-search, web-crawlers, robots.txt, google-chrome

Today I search my GitHub page in Google Chrome and Firefox (Through Google search) and for the first time, it says no information is available (it says 2019- GitHub under that it says no information is available for this page). I read on the internet that it can be due to the Robots.txt file. I follow Google advice at [No page information in search results - Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7489871?hl=en) and download the file checker and it is telling me to upload my file to

`www.github.com/username/`

However, I do not see any place to upload my file (I do not know it is due to do permission, or I cannot find out how to upload my file there).

Other questions on this page, are either talking about personal page or WordPress or something similar. I would like to know can anyone suggest to me how to solve this issue.

**Edit**: I try to add the meta tag as suggested by Google after refreshing the page however it still goes back to the previous content after refreshing the page.  Apparently, **Yahoo search and Bing can find my GitHub page with no problem.**

I also added a snapshot of the Google search. This is what I get after I search my name and then followed by Github keyword

[image]

Comment: Github already has a robots.txt file and it is here: https://github.com/robots.txt I don't see anything it that would disallow username pages unless your username starts with "search"

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks so what do you think is the reason. Yahoo and Bing will show the correct result.  I have contacted GitHub but have not heard yet. Is there anything I should do or anyone I should contact?

Comment: It is unclear to me whether this question is asking about GitHub Pages and `github.io`, or about your GitHub Profile on `github.com`. You mention `github.com/username/` which is a GitHub Profile URL, but then talk about adding meta tags which is only possible with GitHub Pages (`github.io`).

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister This is about my GitHub profile. since this morning when I google my name, it does not bring my GitHub page at all, and when I type my name followed by the keyword GitHub it gives the above information.